# Nest.js bypass class @Guard() for a single resolver

Tags: authentication, nestjs, bypass

I specify guards for `JWT` and `SSO` in my Nest.js api, but now that the project gets larger some specific resolvers need to be accesable by both auth strategies.

I've created a `ChainGuard` which loops through the guards:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChainGuard extends AuthGuard(['jwt', 'sso']) {...}
```

Now I want to use it in one of my resolvers as this:

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JWTGuard } from './jwt.guard';
import { ChainGuard } from './chain.guard';

@Controller('users')
@UseGuards(JWTGuard)
export class UsersController {
  @Get()
  getUsers() {
    // Return list of users
  }

  @Get(':id')
  @UseGuards(ChainGuard)
  getUser(@Param('id') id: string) {
    // Return user details for the given ID
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work as I can't bypass the class guard `JWTGuard`

After researching a bit, most people recommend setting `metadata` for that specific resolver if you are trying to bypass the WHOLE authentication (e.g. public endpoint).
But I'm not trying to do that, I just want to use a different guard while keeping the same old guard for the other resolvers in that Class.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would still end up creating a metadata that is specific to the `JWTGuard`, where `JWTGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt')`. That way, you can skip *that* guard, and still make use of `AuthGuard(['jwt', 'sso'])` (i.e. `ChainGuard`) without worry of that metadata being read, because `ChainGuard` doesn't have the logic for that. Something like

```js
export const SkipJwtGuard = () => SetMetadata('SKIP_JWT_GUARD', true)
```

And in your `JWTGuard` you can use  `this.reflector.get('SKIP_JWT_GUARD', context.getHandler())` and if that returns `true` then you can short circuit *this* guard.